# AngularJS resource not forming url correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem using AngularJS resources.

I have a resource that looks like this:

```
loginModule.service('TestResource', function ($resource, $location) {
    var $scope = this;
    $scope.resource = $resource(window.location.path+'/:event', {event:'@event'});

    $scope.inputData = function(data1, data2, success){
        return $scope.resource.save({'event':'inputData'},{'data1':data1,'data2':data2},success);
    };

    return $scope;
});
```

And yes, I've tried using:

```
//  $scope.resource = $resource($location.path()+'/:event');
//  $scope.resource = $resource(window.location.path+'/:event');
//  $scope.resource = $resource(':event');
```

Firebug reports that the address this tries to send to is one of these two:

```
http://localhost/sandbox/test/undefined/inputData
http://localhost/sandbox/test/:event?event=inputData
```

What I want is an address of:

```
http://localhost/sandbox/test/inputData
```

What am I doing wrong?  More specifically, what should I do to make it right?

Comment: did you try `$resource('/:event'...)`?

Comment: @akonsu That actually gives me `http://localhost/inputData`

Comment: what happens if you remove the slash?

Comment: @akonsu That one gives me `http://localhost/sandbox/test/:event?event=inputData`

Comment: wow. there is probably a bug. my next try would be `./:event`

Comment: Oh!  Hey!  That did it!  Ha-ha!  That did it!  Thank you!  Put that into an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$resource('./:event', ...)`